# Phonegap Build , App icon does not apear

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I am updating my currently app.
Having problems with getting my app icon to show in notification using the Local Notification plugin. 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

I have my notification setup as:

```
    window.plugin.notification.local.schedule({
    id: id,
    ongoing: true,
    autoCancel: false,
    autoClear: false,
    title: "Now Playing:",
    text: title,
    icon: "res://icon.png",
    smallIcon: "res://icon.png",
});
```

I have an icon.png file in the following locations:

```
/www
/www/img
/www/res
```

And even tried the icon and smallIcon values without the res:// but it does not seem to work.

I keep getting a default android notification icon, looks like a bell.

Can anyone please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this problem too. It is due to Phonegap build updating to cli-6.5.0 that happened yesterday. I downgraded to cli-6.0.0 and it worked normally.
Simply add this to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0"/>
```

P.S. Could also work with other versions (for example 6.4.0) but haven't tried it since the above worked.

Comment: 6.4.0, didn't work. 6.0.0 definitely worked. The latest version that seems to work fine is: 6.3.1. Thanks @Bill