# Phonegap build, push notification icon does not appear

Tags: push-notification, phonegap

I was looking at this question:

[Phonegap Build , App icon does not apear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102449/phonegap-build-app-icon-does-not-apear/45200404#45200404)

However, the solution posed is to target an older version of the cli. We'd rather not do that, as it is limiting. Is there a better solution to this that will work with cli-6.5.0?

Comment: issue occurred in iOS or in android ?

Comment: Android. Only on Lollypop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade your version

> android-targetSdkVersion to 20.

In your config.xml file

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20" />
```

may be your version is "23". And android doesn't support icon in 23 version.
So you have to change from 23 to 20 in your android target sdk.

Comment: Drat, I was trying to avoid the downgrade. That's what we've done already, but we're losing out on other features as a result. No workarounds beyond this?

Comment: We don't have any other option.
You have to must downgrade your sdk version to get the icon in push notification.
But this is only your target sdk and its not affect to your other functionalities.